# Error using library(dplyr) in Rstudio: there is no package called ‘lifecycle’

Tags: r, dplyr

i am using this function:

> test = as.data.frame (left_join (registerPers, pers, by = c ("RB030", "PB030")))

but rstudio gives me this error:

*Error in left_join (registerPers, pers, by = c ("RB030", "PB030")):
I can't find the "left_join" function*

despite having downloaded the dplyr package.

I actually find the problem by recalling the package:

> library (dplyr)

*Error: package or namespace load failed for 'dplyr' in loadNamespace (i, c (lib.loc, .libPaths ()), versionCheck = vI [[i]]):
there is no package called 'lifecycle'*

how can i fix it?

Comment: Try `install.packages("lifecycle")`. If you run into additional problems, I'd try re-installing `dplyr` making sure you get all the dependencies, `install.packages("dplyr", dependencies = TRUE)`

Comment: I just tried both tips but i still get the same error!

Answer (score 1):

I had this error and the above solution did not work for me. I also had the message. If you try

```
install.packages("lifecycle")
```

and get an error that looks like this:

> WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed.
> Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
> https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/student/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> also installing the dependencies ‘cli’, ‘rlang’

You will need to go to: https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/ and download the relevant version of RTools, once you have RTools installed rerun the

```
install.packages("lifecycle")
```

command and you should be able to now install it.